# Firefox doesn't show my CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a strange problem, **Firefox 3.6.3** doesn't show the CSS of the page I'm doing, but **Internet Explorer 8** does.

I have tried at home and at one of my friend's home, and it happens in both. But, if I go to the Firefox Web Developer toolbar (i have it installed) and select CSS=>Edit CSS, then the styles appears appears in the page and in the editor! As soon I close it, they disappears again. I have no idea what the problem is :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Students</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

I've validated my two css files with the W3C CSS validator and there are no problems.

Do you have any idea about what could be the problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: it would help if you post snippets from your page of how you reference and load your CSS files.

Comment: Specifically which version of IE does it work in?

Comment: I've added how I declare the css and the browsers' versions.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you move the `<meta> tag` above the `<title>` tag. An encoding problem may occur.

Comment: done, but has no effect.

Comment: Check <link /> with Firebug to see if the CSS is being loaded and the source of the CSS. You may check Web Developer toolbar to see if CSS is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bet a beer that the CSS file is not sending the `content-type: text/css` header. This causes style sheets to not work in Firefox. IE will ignore the content type.

If this is the reason, you should get a warning in the Firefox error console. You can use Firebug's `net` tab to verify the content-type sent.

As to why the content type isn't sent, this would be a server issue I think. It usually happens when the CSS file is a `.php` or `.asp` file that doesn't get assigned the correct content type automatically by the server when delivering.

Comment: You won the beer !!! 

I've set up a handler that handles all requests, so when the browser is asking for .css or images, I have to serve them myself, then I forgot to put the correct ContentType... geez...

Thanks a lot you save my day ;D

Comment: Wow, and even a proper *irish* beer! I would really like that but alas, alas, beer is so hard to post ;)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your css file directly in Firefox (http://www.yoursite.com/style.css) and look at your Page Info (Tools >> Page Info).

If the css file is being submitted as text/html, it's an incorrect MIME type (should be text/css) and you will need to contact your server/host administrator to fix this for you if you don't have access to that.